# best way to build a multilingual site

Tags: php, javascript

I have to build a multilingual website. While searching on the internet I found 3 ways to do.

1. Translation in database
2. Translation in XML files
3. Subdirectories for each language's file

What do you think is the best and more efficient way to do? I need to use SEO techniques and I am working with php, javascript.
The website I'm building is big and has enough text for translation.

Comment: If it's SEO you're worried about, [go straight to the source](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en). In general, the best way to deal with multiple languages is to [let the server redirect the user to a specific file or directory](http://www.howtoforge.com/using-apache2-content-negotiation-to-serve-different-languages) based on their browser settings.

Comment: So you say I must choose option 3?

Comment: You should take a look at gnu gettext. Anyhow, method you chose for translation has nothing to do with SEO. Thats another story. http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php

Comment: You don't *have* to choose option 3, but Google prefers it.

Comment: @Blazemonger nonsense, look at mr Pavlikovs comment.. since htaccess exists URL and directories have nothing in common.

Comment: @Tomas Read about Google's recommendations. For SEO purposes, it's best not to have different textual content at the same URL for different language settings.

Answer (score 1):

I use 4rd way - [gettext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext) and [its associated PHP library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php). Seems far more simple than any other techniques mentioned - in the sense of making no complications at all in the code. In your code, you just write:

```
<?php

    echo _("Hello world");
    echo _("This is an english message.");

?>
```

And that's it! Then in some initialization code I have:

```
    bindtextdomain ('messages', './lang');
    textdomain('messages');
```

And in the directory ./lang I have gettext translation files.